# Entity Framework DbContext code generation generates incorrect code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation

I'm using VS2010 with Entity Framework (file version is 4.4. product version is 5)

I have installed the EF5.x `DbContext` generator.

After creating my `.edmx` file, I right clicked on the empty space and added a new `DbContext` template, which generated the `context.tt` and `.tt` files.

However, in the `.tt` files, this is how the auto generated code looks like:

```
namespace DataObjects.EntityFramework.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class SubSystem
    {
        public string SubSystemId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Fmode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastBackup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the using statements are inside the namespace, which gives rise to a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those compilation errors must be related to something else, because it's perfectly legal in C# to have using statements in the namespace.

Verify that you've added all of the correct references, [such as EntityFramework.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)