# EF 5.x DbContext Generator - Namespace Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to update a project to work in ASP.NET MVC4 using EF5(Database First approach as there is an existing db). I'm doing this with VS2010.

I am following the steps in this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx).

These are the steps that I'm taking:

- Set up a new MVC4 project simply called *Project.NET*
- Create the Entity Data Model as *ProjectModel.edmx*
- The connection string is saved as *ProjectEntities*
- The model namespace is set to *ProjectModel*
- Add an EF 5.x DbContext Generator item called *ProjectModel.tt*

So after all that, it has created the classes to be used by EF; the problem is that these classes are all created with the project's root namespace, rather than the namespace I have provided it.

If I open up any of the generated classes, I get a list of errors that are fixed by manually changing the namespace to *ProjectModel*

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

**Update:**
[image: Project Structure] 
This is a screenshot showing the project structure, an example of the generated code, and the compiler errors.

What's odd is that it only seems to throw an error for a namespace based on the structure, so in the image *Project.Models* as the namespace creates an issue, but if I type in anything else such as *ProjectModels* or *Test* the errors disappear. I can change the the namespace on all the files, sure, but every time the model changes and is updated, the namespace will be reset and the errors return.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060614/entity-framework-dbcontext-code-generation-generates-incorrect-code) question seems to be the same issue as the one I am having, but unfortuntely, the only answer given advised checking references; I believe mine are fine as System.Data.Entity and EntityFramework are present.

**Update 2:**
If I don't select all tables to during the code generation no namespace issues appear. I'm currently updating the model in 20 table intervals, with 400 tables though, I'd rather figure out what the actual issue is. I'm assuming it is due to the structure or name of one or more tables, but I'm not sure on whether or not there are any specific rules with regard table structure or naming with regard to EF.

Comment: As a common standard, and I'm not getting this from your question. If you have classes with namespaces more specific than your apps' root namespace, they should be organized into folders where the folder name is the namespace your classes are contained.

Comment: Yeh, I've tried having it in a separate folder and a separate project. Neither helped.

Comment: can you post more details about the layout of your project and the generated code?

Comment: I've updated my post, hopefully it'll help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your project is targeting .NET 2.0. Right-click on your project and choose Properties. make sure **Target framework** is set to .NET 4 or later.

Comment: It's definitely set to .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though one of the tables which is called *System* was conflicting with the .NET *System* namespace. I guess I'll just have to change the table name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adverse to making changes to your data schema, you can configure Entity Framework to map the table name to a different type/class. Something like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/codefirst-ef-4-1-changing-database-table-and-column-name.aspx) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to set a custom namespace for the generated classes by setting the `Custom Tool Namespace` field in the .edmx model properties, and also in the properties of both the `.tt` files under it, using the Properties window.